# How to start a query in Laravel with Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm trying to write the following code:

```php
foreach($relations as $relation){
    $query->orWhereHas($relation, function ($query) use ($filter) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$filter.'%');
    });
}
```

but I don't know how to initialize the $query variable, I'd prefer not to write the first orWhereHas before the foreach starts.
Anyone knows how to achieve this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Show all code from model

Comment: `$query = Model::query();`

Comment: Thanks user2094178! That works! <3

Comment: @user2094178 You may want to use your comment as an answer

Comment: Thanks for the info :D

Answer (score 11):

Eloquent models has `query()` method. Then, you can do this

```
$query = App\User::query();
```